# Java - Deserialize JSON response with multiple date formats

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, jackson, json-deserialization

I am using java 17 and spring boot 3 and am trying to deserialize the following json response.

```json
{
    "updated": "Sep 13, 2023 19:24:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2023-09-13T19:24:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Sep 13, 2023 at 20:24 BST"
}
```

I have created the following java object

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {

    private LocalDateTime updated;

    private LocalDateTime updatedISO;

    @JsonProperty("updateduk")
    private LocalDateTime updatedUK;

}
```

The dates in the json response are all in different formats and I would like to deserialise them all to a local date time if possible.

I have tried the following annotations with various different patterns but I haven't been able to make it work

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate target is the first hit on a search for "json deserialize multiple date formats".  The interwebs are your friend, if you ask.

Comment: Do not use `LocalDateTime` when you are getting time zone or UTC offset in the input. You need to preserve those in order to interpret the dates and times into points on the time line.

Comment: It is the same point in time coming in three different representations? So you might ignore the two of them and just use one? Better for validation of course to deserialize each of the three and verify that the *are* the same.

Comment: @OleV.V. Fair enough, reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement your own deserializer for dates. Example for "updatedISO":

```
public class IsoDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    public IsoDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String value = jsonParser.readValueAs(String.class);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }
}
```

And for other fields:

```
public class PatternDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    public PatternDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String value = jsonParser.readValueAs(String.class);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ROOT);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
    }
}
```

So then you will be able to configure your class like:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = PatternDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime updated;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = IsoDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime updatedISO;

    @JsonProperty("updateduk")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PatternDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime updatedUK;

}
```

For the `updateduk` field you will need format pattern `MMM dd, uuuu 'at' HH:mm z`, though.

Comment: This is the way to go about it, thank you (+1). Only, as I already commented under the question, we should not use `LocalDateTime` but `OffsetDateTime` for the ISO string, `ZonedDateTime` for the UK string and either of them for the plain `updated` field in UTC or perhaps even `Instant`.

Comment: I also had to add an if statetment in PatternDateTimeDeserializer because the updateduk date was in a different format.  ```if (value.contains("at")) {
            formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu 'at' HH:mm z", Locale.ROOT);
        } else {
            formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ROOT);
        }```

Comment: *I also had to add an if statetment ...* That should work. Rather than an `if` statement I would find it nicer to code to subclasses of `PatternDateTimeDeserializer` with the two different patterns. Then use one of them for `updated`, the other for `updatedUk`. Also checking for occurrence of `at` is smart enough only as long as there isn’t any day of week in the string. `Saturday` contains `at`!